# UINavigationBarButtons changed their color to white

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

UINavigationBarButtons changed their color to white  in Whole Application after iOS 11 Upgrade How to change ?

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: Yes I tried to change Bar button tint color, but didn't help. it tase some white layer on it when pressing button behind layer i saw the button color but when i throw my hand it didn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.red
```

call this line, it's a proxy method for the time being working on iOS 11

Comment: It Doesn't help i used it for MFMessageComposeViewController and The Cancel button has some white layer on it. and did't change tint color

Comment: And it works normally on iOS 10 but in iOS 11 it has this issue